# Decrease The Entire Header Section To 45px

Tags: html, css, joomla

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxDGG.png)

LINK: https://gta.stillwaters.io/

Can anyone help me make the entire header area height 45px? That's about 3 times the size of the font and also, decrease the logo height also. The logo and header area seems too long in height. If that entire could be reduced to 45px?

```
header.hidden-phone {height: 45px;}
```

Code above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a padding on your header, the rendering engine goes outwards. it first renders the inner box with the specified height then it renders a "frame" that contains that box with the width specified on each side.
I recommend you to disable padding on this element. more information at [w3 schools box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)
and there is another attribute that can help [Box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the padding on `#sp-header-wrapper` in order to get your header to 45px.
So change this:

```
#sp-header-wrapper {
    padding: 20px 0 !important;
}
#sp-header-wrapper {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#sp-header-wrapper {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
#sp-main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 1% 0;
}
```

To this:

```
#sp-header-wrapper {padding: 0 !important;}
#sp-header-wrapper {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
#sp-main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then resize your logo:

```
div#sp-logo {
    height: inherit;
}
div.logo-wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
}
img.image-logo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: couldn't hack it